# Safari renders strange lines when using border-radius

Tags: css, safari

I'm facing a strange rendering issue with safari when using border-radius and border.

The HTML is

```html
<div id="box"></div>
```

CSS:

```css
body {
    background-color: #666;
}

#box {
    width: 700px;
    height: 300px;

    background-color: white;
    
    border-radius: 8px;
    border-top: 8px solid green;
}
```

The round borders are rendering just fine but safari adds some strange dotted diagonal lines on the inside of the round corners.

Here is a screenshot with zoom: [image]

Here is a demo: https://jsfiddle.net/mgfz0tsd/1/

I assume this is a rendering bug in safari because in no other browser this happens. Is there any workaround?

EDIT: It seems to be related to the screen resolution and only happen on 4k or other big resolutions.

Comment: In my Mac/safari it's okay.

Comment: I can reproduce on Safari 13.1.3 / Catalina

Comment: It might be related to the screen resolution and only happen with 4k or other big resolutions